# How to add windows library to Visual Studio Static Library project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, static, static-libraries, static-linking

In my VS2010 Visual C++ project, I need to add a few Windows libraries to access socket functionality. I know how to add a library to executable project (Properties --> Linker --> Input); I do not see the same option when I change my project type to "Static Library". How do I add windows libraries to a Static Library output project?

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hope the question clear enough?